# How can I use my own filter with Cups

Tags: cups

by the past I was able to use homemade filter to support a legacy system  with a specific printer name.

```
lpadmin -p PCL2PRINTER -i /root/pcltoprinter.sh -v cups-pdf:/ -E
```

I used this often and my script is really helpfull but now I am no more able to use such filter because its looks like lpadmin do not support filter no more. I got the error `lpadmin: Unable to open PPD "/root/pcl2printer.sh": Missing asterisk in column 1 on line 1.`
lpadmin only accept ppd file but no more scripts ?

If I manually put my script in `/etc/cups/interfaces/PCL2PRINTER` it is not taken into account.

Do you have an idea on how can I set my scripts so any printing going to a specific printer will go through my script.

edit : solution -> uninstall apparmor that suddenly blocked my scripts from running. (too bad)

Comment: I don't know if this will do it, but there is [Tea4CUPS](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTea4CUPS) which can add a wrapper around a backend. Depending on your printer you might also look at the new [LPrint](https://www.msweet.org/lprint/) utility for label printers (Dymo, Zebra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstall apparmor that suddenly blocked my scripts from running.